# Proper way to reload rsyslog with a config file for a custom application

Tags: rsyslog

I want to log my app so that it writes its log into its own log file. I create the log file and save it under `/etc/rsyslog.d`but my app doesn't create/write to the designated file. However, once I reload rsyslog, there are log entries the next time my app runs.

I package my app into an RPM so I can write post-install scripts if necessary. Is this the proper way to handle this via post-install scripts?

## /etc/rsyslog.d/serf.conf

```
if $programname == 'serf' then /var/log/serf.log
& ~
```

Sending `pkill -HUP rsyslog` works but I wasn't sure if that would cause any issues to other programs while they're in the middle of logging.

Answer (score 5):

Sending SIGHUP can't reload the rsyslog configure files, but only reopens the log files for rotating. Restart should reload the config files.

see https://lists.gt.net/rsyslog/users/16151

Comment: Which is correct, but highly sub-optimal. For example, queued but not yet written log packets, and networked packets will be lost. Also active TCP and unix-stream logging connections will broke. My personal opinion is that I found it catastrophal, that the rsyslog developers couldn't solve this trivial problem long ago.

Comment: The solution I could find for this problem: [syslog-ng](https://www.syslog-ng.com/) *can* stop rule processing with `flags(final)`, it also can reload configuration without data loss, so rsyslog can (and needs to) be eliminated from any system where logging is important.